# Python error when upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, python, 19.04

I have Python 2.7.15+ symlinked to `python` and Python 3.6.7 symlinked to `python3`. When I try to upgrade Ubuntu to 19.04 with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-k7w2kx7r/disco", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2085, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1906, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askLivepatch():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1175, in askLivepatch
    version = next((r.version for r in di.get_all("object") if r.series == self.toDist), self.toDist)
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-k7w2kx7r/disco", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2085, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1906, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askLivepatch():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1175, in askLivepatch
    version = next((r.version for r in di.get_all("object") if r.series == self.toDist), self.toDist)
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

I tried to upgrade all Python packages before upgrading Ubuntu:

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Is that why it fails?

Comment: I'm back on this question because I got this problem upgrading 19.10 to 20.04.

Comment: and once again 20.04 to 20.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This seems to typically stem from a pip-installed version of distro-info shadowing the apt version [...]
>
> If you're here looking for a quick fix:
>
> ```
> sudo python3 -m pip uninstall distro-info
> sudo apt reinstall python3-distro-info
> ```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874250/comments/9

Comment: Ran into this upgrading 20.04 to 20.10 and can confirm that this works

Comment: Ran into this problem in 2022 trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS and it still works :).  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I solved the question by myself.

I find the problemed python script:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/distro_info.py
```

Then cover it by:

```
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/distro-info/raw/master/python/distro_info.py
```

then run sudo do-release-upgrade, successfully.

Comment: this seems a bit unsafe, @Ahmed's answer is safer.