# do-release-upgrade (19.10) python errors

Tags: 19.10, do-release-upgrade

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and am up to date with that version's updates.  I would like to upgrade to 20.04.  As Root I entered the following command - 'do-release-upgrade -d' and I am receiving multiple Python errors and the process fails.  The command output error follows.  Any suggestions?

Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 186, in _get_from_and_to_version
    di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0]
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/focal", line 8, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2082, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1919, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 925, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 97, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 116, in focalPostInitialUpdate
    self._get_from_and_to_version()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 192, in _get_from_and_to_version
    (r.version for r in di.get_all("object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 186, in _get_from_and_to_version
    di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0]
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/focal", line 8, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2082, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1919, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 925, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 97, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 116, in focalPostInitialUpdate
    self._get_from_and_to_version()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4t_e6y6y/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 192, in _get_from_and_to_version
    (r.version for r in di.get_all("object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'

Comment: I tried forcing a reinstall of the upgrader core with the command 'apt install --reinstall ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' but I am getting the same error messages afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137645/python-error-when-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04)

Answer (score 0):

For this to be happening you likely have a pip install of distro-info which does not provide the same information as the Ubuntu package python-distro-info.