# software-properties-gtk: AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'

Tags: software-center, update-manager

When running the `software-properties-gtk`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

Tried a bunch of things, from reinstalling it, trying to reinstall or install different dependencies...

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.init_distro()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 392, in init_distro
    distro = current_distro()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/utils.py", line 72, in current_distro
    releases = di.get_all(result="object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137645/python-error-when-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04)